# Can We Define a Type of Integral Over an Interval Whose Partition Approaches Being Uncountably Infinite?

Tags: integration

My background is physics and engineering, not specifically mathematics though, of course, I learned some advanced mathematics for my profession. So, please forgive me if my terminology could be more technically precise or correct, and I welcome suggestions on how to make it so.

A Riemann integral of a function, $f$, over an interval, $[0,1]$, of the real-valued $x$ axis results in the partition approaching being countably infinite, as the upper limit (stopping point; an integer) of $\Sigma$ approaches infinity . This means that not every real number in the interval becomes a member of the partition. Also, $f$ is only evaluated at a number of points in the interval that is countably infinite, and is not evaluated at every point in the interval.

Is there a way to generalize the concept of integral so that every real number in the interval of integration is included in the partition? That would also result in $f$ being evaluated at every real value of $x$ in the interval.  I have no idea how to do this, but just wondering if it can be done and if it would converge even for well behaved test functions.

The reason I am asking is motivated by my experience in physics. For a discrete physical variable, $k$, you can define $\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(k)$ where $f$ is evaluated at every point in the discrete interval $[1,n]$. $f$ can be represented as a vector if the range of k is finite. If we generalize $k$ to a continuous variable, $x$, then the generalization of the sum is an integral, $\int_{1}^{n} f(x) dx$, but $f$ is no longer evaluated at every value of $x$ in the interval of integration. So, I was wondering if there was a way to define integral such that for both the sum of a function of a discrete variable or the integral of a function of a continuous variable, the function, $f$, is evaluated at every value of the variable in the interval of interest. Of course, I would want the result of the integral, defined in this way, to be the same as it is when defined in the traditional way, since we know that the traditional way yields physically meaningful results.

This is just a kind of pure thought question. I am just wondering, that is all. There is no specific need for what I am asking about.

Comment: The definition of the Riemann integral is a bit more subtle; it requires that the sum is close to the final value for *every possible* (sufficiently fine) partition. Although each partition uses only finitely many values of $f$, between all partitions considered by the definition, $f$ is actually evaluated at every point in the interval. Once we know the Riemann integral exists (eg because $f$ is continuous), this ensures any sequence of partitions will give the same answer, so we can just compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum f(k/n)$ for example.

Comment: @stewbasic Thank you for your response! But if the size of the partition ends up approaching being only countably infinite, and $f$ is evaluated only once per subinterval, and the number of points in the real interval of integration is uncountably infinite, then how can $f$ actually be evaluated at every point in the interval?

Comment: Actually, integrals work in the opposite way: they can only be defined for functions whose information is essentially countable. This is because the notion of size that abides our intuition behaves well only under countable operations and not beyond.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for your comment. So, you mean that the function only has different values at a countably infinite number of x values? Not sure what "whose information is essentially countable" means. Thanks.

Comment: There is a notion of information called *measurability*. Formally this is a family of sets satisfying certain criteria, but the intuition is that this captures the notion of information which is accessible from basic information through countably many operations. A quintessential example is the Borel measurability on $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is obtained from open balls. Now let me allude the details, but the catch is that both the functions and the notion of size need to be describable by measurable sets in order to obtain a satisfactory theory of integrals.

Comment: @SangchulLee Got it. So, then my original question still stands: Is there a way to generalize the notion of integral to work for functions whose info is uncountable. That would also make the partition of the integral uncountable, I would think.

Comment: Thankfully, any sensible (and perhaps physically meaningful) functions between Euclidean spaces are (Borel) measurable, so in application to real world problems you never need to worry about measurability. You will need to invoke a very special construction using Axiom of Choice (AC) just to create a non-measurable function, and any such function will never be able to be explicitly described. And finally, I am not telling you that we cannot extend the theory of integrals to a broader family of functions, but I have no idea what will come out...

Comment: @SangchulLee Is another way to interpret "functions whose information is essentially countable" is that if you sample the function, in order to digitize it, you only need a sample size that is countably infinite? So, it relates to Nyquist rate and Fourier Analysis of the function?